# Add parameter to __init__ in function

Tags: python, python-2.7, constructor, keyword-argument

Here is the original `main.py` code

```
kwargs = {
    "ffmpeg":    args.ffmpeg,
    "rtmpdump":  args.rtmpdump,
    "swfrender": args.swfrender,
    }

with presentation.Downloader(pres, **kwargs) as builder:
```

that initializes this `Downloader` class

```
class Downloader(object):
    def __init__(self, presentation, overwrite="-n", ffmpeg="ffmpeg", rtmpdump="rtmpdump", swfrender="swfrender"):
        self.presentation = presentation
        self.ffmpeg = ffmpeg
        self.rtmpdump = rtmpdump
        self.swfrender = swfrender
```

When I add an extra argument `overwrite`

```
    kwargs = {
        "ffmpeg":    args.ffmpeg,
        "rtmpdump":  args.rtmpdump,
        "swfrender": args.swfrender,
        "overwrite": "-y" if args.overwrite else "-n",
        }

    with presentation.Downloader(pres, **kwargs) as builder:

class Downloader(object):
    def __init__(self, presentation, overwrite="-n", ffmpeg="ffmpeg", rtmpdump="rtmpdump", swfrender="swfrender", overwrite="-n"):
        self.presentation = presentation
        self.ffmpeg = ffmpeg
        self.rtmpdump = rtmpdump
        self.swfrender = swfrender
        self.overwrite = overwrite
```

python produces this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "infoqscraper/main.py", line 374, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "infoqscraper/main.py", line 369, in main
    module.main(infoq_client, args.module_args)
  File "infoqscraper/main.py", line 191, in main
    return command.main(infoq_client, args.command_args)
  File "infoqscraper/main.py", line 307, in main
    with presentation.Downloader(pres, **kwargs) as builder:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'overwrite'
```

How do I correctly add an argument?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, but are you certain you saved your `Downloader.__init__()` changes?

Comment: Have you noticed you're specifing `overwrite="-n"` twice?

Comment: you want to add two arguments `overwrite` ? that doesn't make sense to have twice the variable as function input.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, saved everytime I make changes and run `python`
@YerayDiazDiaz yes, redundant in __init__, but when I take out `="-n"` I still get the same error
@StephaneRolland I want to add only a single overwrite variable

Comment: @hanxue: take out the whole `overwrite="-n"` argument, leave only one such argument in there. However, if you *did* put two in there, that'd be a syntax error: `SyntaxError: duplicate argument 'overwrite' in function definition`. If you *didn't* get such a syntax error, you didn't save the file (or didn't edit the file you thought you did).